# Strange Future Warning Error after Vpython Installation

Tags: python, numpy, vpython

First I installed Python 2.7.6 (Windows, 32-bit version), then numpy 1.9.1, and then VPython 6.10. After that, I'm getting this error:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import visual

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\visual_common\materials.py", line 70
    self.__setattr__(key, value)
FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.

>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>>
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score -1):

A Quick Google for "FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future."

turned up:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/58863

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4894

Try there see if it answers your question.

Comment: Well i went through the above mentioned links and all i could get is that instead of comparing any value to None using == , we should use "is" keyword. But now the question is how to modify __setattr__ module which is builtin function.

Comment: Unfortunately if it is a bug in that module, you can only raise an issue or submit a patch.